# Crontab edit cron tasks within terminal

Tags: bash, cron

I am new to bash and I am creating a program that will allow a user to manage crontab with a user interface. I want to create an option to select a cron task. I have it listing a number before the task but I want to be able to select an individual line by typing the line number. EG it will look like:

```
0 * * * * mkdir TEST

.@reboot echo RESTART
```

etc..

```
SELECT 1

0 * * * * mkdir TEST (This is the part where you are allowed to edit the task)
```

How would it be possible to achieve this.

Here's my code so far:

```
if [[ $INPUT == "3" ]]; then
      echo "Here is the current crontab entries:"
      crontab -l | awk '{ print NR ". " $0 }' 
      read -p "Please select a task: " TASKSELECT
```

That is as far as I have got with that part and I'm not too sure how to proceed. I assume it can be achieved by selecting the crontab file and searching for the line number or something.

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing the `select` statement.

Comment: How would I go around using the select statement to select the individual line within the crontab file.

Comment: Basically `OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; select choice in $(crontab -l); do ... done; IFS=$OLDIFS`. The index that the user picked is in `$REPLY`.